# Bulk changing SSRS schedules

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have around 100 SQL Server Reporting Services subscriptions that I need to change the schedule on.  The schedules are all standalone, not shared.

Is there a way that I can easily bulk change the report schedules?

Moving them all to handful of common shared schedules would also be acceptable, but again I'd rather not have to do it manually.

I've been experimenting with Powershell to talk to the Reporting Services web service, but it seems far from straightforward to edit schedules, so I'm hoping that there's an easier way.

Comment: Is this schedule via SQL agent job?

Comment: The schedules are created via the SSRS Report Manager, but do ultimately create agent jobs.  Can I just change the agent job schedule without amending the SSRS job itself?

Comment: If you give a try on one of the jobs via sql agent, what do you see? does it change in ssrs itself?

Comment: I've just tried a couple of tests - the report runs on the new agent job schedule, but sadly it doesn't update SSRS itself.

Comment: Ah, your thinking got me searching in another direction, and I found this: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/not-a-fan-of-the-report-manager-in-ssrs/ which looks like a slightly less insane approach than using powershell, so I'm going to have a play with that and see how I get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question that I actually landed on in my quest trying to accomplish the same task recently.  I wanted to follow up with my solution in case someone else lands here as well.

I actually wrote a few functions in powershell to get the job done.
You can see the code and process [here](https://www.warrenestes.com/update-multiple-ssrs-subscriptions/)

Comment: I ended up changing my subscriptions by hand because I didn't want to risk my sanity by dealing with the SOAP API - but I appreciate you sharing your work, if I ever need to do this again, I know exactly where to go!

Comment: funnily enough this came up again today, and I looked back at my question to find your link.  I nearly wet my pants with excitement when I saw your link to the Microsoft ReportingServicesTools PowerShell module ;)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have recently published a ReportingServicesTools PowerShell module that helps massively with any kind of bulk administration tasks.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools